# embed sound so that when publish we do not have to include it in the same folder as the swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, publish, audio, flash-cs3

i have a flash animation with sound that have play,pause,stop,go to start and go to end button.

when i publish it i have to include the mp3 file along with the swf file.

how do i do to get the swf file alone in order to play the whole thing?

i am using flash cs 3 and actionscript 3.0

here is my codes:

`var mySound:Sound = new Sound();`

`var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();`

`var lastPosition:Number = 0;`

`var soundIsPlaying:Boolean = true;`

`mySound.load(new URLRequest("saloma.mp3"));`

`myChannel = mySound.play();`

all those buttons will go to functions,

`go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,govid);`

`function govid(event:MouseEvent):void{`

`play();`

`if(!soundIsPlaying){`

`myChannel = mySound.play(lastPosition);`

`soundIsPlaying = true;`

`}`

`}`

i am also using scenes to navigate them,

`gte.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoend);`

`function gotoend(event:MouseEvent):void{`

`gotoAndStop(1,"ending");`

`}`

thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have written the answer, but this has been answered already...

---

First, in your library, set the class linkage of a sound file by right clicking, selecting properties and editing the Class field in the Linkage section. In this example it will be Class:FogHorn

```
 import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;    
 var SoundClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("FogHorn") as Class;
 var newSound:Sound = new SoundClass(); 
 newSound.play()
```

---

source: @[Allan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133657/allan) in [Actionscript 3: playing sound from library with name from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569048/actionscript-3-playing-sound-from-library-with-name-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

1. import your mp3 file to your library
2. select your mp3 file in the library and right click on it
3. a pop-up window will appear (click on advanced if it is not yet clicked)
4. under the actionscript linkage, you will see class field, type "sound1" for example (no 5. quotations, this can be any other name aside from sound1)
5. instead of var mySound:Sound = new Sound(); this code, type
   var mySound:Sound = new sound1(); //sound1 is the name of your linkage/class
6. You don't need this codes anymore. You need to omit your myChannel variable.

mySound.load(new URLRequest("saloma.mp3"));

myChannel = mySound.play();

1. To play the sound, simply type
   mySound.play();